# Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 SQL Server Error

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am running a sproc on an SQL Server 2005 server which is resulting in the following error:

> Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A
>   transport-level error has occurred
>   when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

Once the error occurs I loose my connection to the server, but able to reconnect.
There is nothing in the Event logs.
The database is still functional and running its website fine.
EDIT: This occurs every time I run this sproc, or it's called by an application.

Any suggestions on what may be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the DB server is made unavailable with a client connection open.

To reproduce: If you have a query open in SSMS, restart the SQL instance, run the query again to get this error.

Thoughts:

- Is the SQL instance being restarted?
- Is the DB being [closed automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249(SQL.90).aspx)? (eg desktop editions, don't use them myself though)
- Firewall issues?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

This may be caused when you have connection pooling enabled, and for whatever reason, one connection in the pool loses its connection to the DB (due to a network hickup, or any other reason).

Is this happening everytime you call this sproc?

Does that sproc attempt to access a linked server?

Comment: Yeah, this is happening every time I run the sproc, and I strongly believe it's happening when an application calls the sproc too.